# Three.js v74 and up don't support LatheGeometry

Tags: three.js, geometry

I'm unable to launch my project in `three.js` v74 and any other newer version. It works just fine with v73, but it seems like newer versions don't support `LatheGeometry`.

Look at these images and compare

V73:

[image: First picture v73]

To v76:

[image: Second picture v76]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LatheGeometry` and `LatheBufferGeometry` now take an array of `Vector2` as input.

```
var points = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {
        points.push( new THREE.Vector2( Math.sin( i * 0.2 ) * 10 + 5, ( i - 5 ) * 2 ) );
    }
var geometry = new THREE.LatheGeometry( points );
```

The points are defined in the xy-plane, and are rotated around the y-axis to create the shape. The x-coordinate of each point must be greater than zero.

three.js r.76

Comment: Thank you so much!